# An error occurs while pushing the code to GitHub

Tags: github, git-push

Upon executing 'git push,' an error is being displayed to me.

`git push`

Enumerating objects: 3310, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3310/3310), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3292/3292), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3308/3308), 16.78 MiB | 73.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 3308 (delta 252), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
**error: RPC failed; curl 55 Send failure: Broken pipe
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date**

[Show error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE1Qd.png)

Initially, I attempted the following sequence:

Checked the status with `git status`
Added all changes using `git add --all`
Committed changes with `git commit -m "changes"`
Pushed the changes using `git push`

However, an error emerged at this point.